# Bidirectional scrollable table/grid

Tags: android, scrollview, drawable, android-gridview, android-tablelayout

I have to create a table of items in an Android Fragment which can exceed both the width and the height, so it would need to be scrolled on both ways. Think of a TV Guide with the hours on the horizontal axis and channels on the vertical axis. Each item in the table is actionable (statelistdrawable containing bitmaps).
How would you implement this most efficiently considering:

1. There is not default bidirectional scrollview. I added a HorizontalScrollView in a ScrollView and it worked ok although it is reported to cause problems.
2. There should be a mechanism to lazy load the views that are not visible (similar to listview adapter behaviour)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about using ViewPagerIndicator and ViewPager. There is even a library that lets you use icons as indicators: http://viewpagerindicator.com/

With the ViewPagerIndicator you can indicate the hours horizontally and a listview inside each fragment would take care of the channels